# Firebase Authentication: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm trying to set up Google Authentication with Firebase in a Flutter app.

I'm getting this error on Android:

```
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
```

It occurs at line:

```
GoogleSignInAccount? user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
```

I have tried:

- Adding SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys for both release and debug. I am manually doing the key signing for release, so its not a problem with the Android Studio versioning, but I have checked to ensure the keys are accurate which they are.
- Adding a support email to Firebase
- Adding the line "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services''" to my app\build.gradle.
- Checking that I have added the correct dependencies using BOM to my app\build.gradle.
- Adding the "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'" dependency to my android\build.gradle.
- Checking that the AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle have the same class name as my flutter project.
- Checking that the google-services.json file is correct.
- Running "flutter clean" many times.
- Checking that Google Authentication is enabled.

It works on iOS so it's most likely not a code issue. It works on neither debug or release. Reading from Firestore is working fine, so the google-services.json shouldn't be the issue. I had a similar project with OAuth Consent set up that didn't fix the issue (and the google authentication never started working), so I haven't done it here because it is time consuming.

I have checked so many StackOverflow questions and none of the solutions work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had changed the package name from what I was using in Firebase. I had it changed in google-services.json. But I had to create custom OAuth keys using my new package name for each key I needed to work.